# Why aren't the integrals $\int_{-1}^2 \sqrt{t^2}\sqrt{9t^2+4} \,dt$ and $\int_{-1}^2 t\sqrt{9t^2+4} \,dt$ equal?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm a bit confused by the two integrals below. Why aren't they equal? What am I missing?

$\int_{-1}^2 \sqrt{t^2}\sqrt{9t^2+4} \,dt = 10,51$

$\int_{-1}^2 t\sqrt{9t^2+4} \,dt = 7,63$

Comment: You are assuming $\sqrt{t^2}=t$.

Comment: Because $t\ne\sqrt{t^2}$ in general.

Comment: Always use : $\sqrt{t^2}=|t|$, to be correct and consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$\sqrt{t^2}=|t|$$ they are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand of the second integral is negative on $(-1,0)$, while the first is not.